# Is there a command to hide/show this info sub-window in Window Explorer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Is there a command to hide/show this info sub-window (magenta highlight) in Window Explorer? I find none on the menu. And if there is, what's the keyboard shortcut? Else is there any way the panel can be hidden/shown using the keyboard?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Organize -> Layout -> Details pane

As it looks like there is no keyboard shortcut (see [here](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/windows-7-keyboard-shortcuts-to-increase-productivity/)). There is one for Preview Pane (`Alt`+`Shift`+`P`) but for some reason not for the Details Pane. You will have to do it with your mouse.

Comment: Thanks. I see no keyboard shortcut. That command takes 13 keypresses from focus pictured.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I overlooked that you are looking for a heyboard shortcut.

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: Well, you answered the main question so I have given the Green Tick, and the info that there is no key is useful because it saves me searching :)  Thanks!